# array_combine function with duplicate value

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
$codes = 'test1,test1,test3';
$names = '1226261693assistenza-pc-1-1.jpeg,1226261693cobinhood.png,1226261693a.png';
$array = array_combine ( explode(',',$codes), explode(',', $names) );

foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{

   echo $k."<br>";
   echo $v."<br>";
}

?>
```

How to get duplicate value in array combine function. 
I would appreciate any help and tips.

Comment: format your question better

Comment: Do you want to filter out duplicate values ? Maybe you could add an example with duplicate values.